# Oracle SQL returning rows same max value

Tags: sql, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

Here is my table

```
 ------------------
|__fruit__|_color_|
| banana  | yellow|
| lemon   | yellow|
| apple   |  red  |
| cherry  |  red  |
| lime    | green |
```

The output from the query should be:

```
yellow, banana
yellow, lemon
red, apple
red, cherry
```

I'm wanting to return the fruit with the maximum amount of the count of color. Since both the color red and the color yellow have the same maximum amount of color, I havent been able to get them both.
I have tried using `distinct` keywords, as well as trying different aggregate functions using `count` but have only been able to return one color.

Comment: Kindly share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `group by` color and `join` it to the original table to get the desired result.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/849ff/15)

```
with cnts as (select color,count(*) as cnt
from tablename 
group by color)
, maxcnt as (select max(cnt) as mxcnt from cnts)
select t.color,t.fruit
from cnts c join maxcnt m on c.cnt = m.mxcnt
join tablename t on t.color = c.color
```

Comment: The edited version only returns red and not yellow, and is much more confusing for a beginner.

Comment: the earlier version..was explicitly returning all rows where `count` was > 1. However, with the modified version, you get only rows for colors where there is a maximum count, which was your question. Also, i added more rows in the fiddle for your understanding